# How to handle missed workouts before a race?

Tags: triathlon

I'm in the middle of a training regimen for my 5th Ironman race (Race is in September).  Based on family commitments, I'll be traveling for about 3 weeks in August to locations that make cycling prohibitively difficult for me.

Transporting one of my bikes would be prohibitively expensive, as would buying one while I'm there.  I looked into rental and stationary options, and while they might work for the shorter workouts, finding bikes that would simulate race conditions well enough (e.g. cleats, aero bars, etc) doesn't look like it's in the cards.  So at a time when I should be peaking my rides at 5-6 hours of riding in the longest workouts, I'm simply not going to be able to. I worry that using a conventional bike or stationary bike would possibly do more harm than good, overtraining my quads and undertraining my glutes, hams, and back.

What other options am I missing for at least maintaining my riding form and fitness during this critical time?  I will likely have only about 2-3 weeks of peak training left after returning before I should start tapering for the race.